# Pandas get column value based on row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'flag': ['col3', 'col2', 'col2'],
                        'col1': [1, 3, 2], 
                        'col2': [5, 2, 4], 
                        'col3': [6, 3, 6], 
                        'col4': [0, 4, 4]},
                        index=pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C'], name='index'))
```

| index | flag | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | col3 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 0 |
| B | col2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| C | col2 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 4 |

For each row, I want to get the value when column name is equal to the `flag`.

| index | flag | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | col3 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 6 |
| B | col2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| C | col2 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 4 |

– Index `A` has a flag of `col3`. So `col_val` should be 6 because `df['col3']` for that row is 6.
– Index `B` has a flag of `col2`. So `col_val` should be 2 because `df['col2']` for that row is 2.
– Index `C` has a flag of `col2`. So `col_val` should be 4 because `df['col2']` for that row is 3.

Comment: you are doing a lookup; the pandas docs has an [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) that you can adapt to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['flag'])
df['COl_VAL'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       flag  col1  col2  col3  col4  COl_VAL
index                                       
A      col3     1     5     6     0        6
B      col2     3     2     3     4        2
C      col2     2     4     6     4        4
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs has an [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) that you can adapt; the solution is below is just another option.

What it does is flip the dataframe into a MultiIndex dataframe, select the relevant columns and trim it to non nulls::

```py
 cols = [(ent, ent) for ent in df.flag.unique()]
 (df.assign(col_val = df.pivot(index = None, columns = 'flag')
                        .loc(axis = 1)[cols].sum(1)
 )

        flag  col1  col2  col3  col4  col_val
index
A      col3     1     5     6     0      6.0
B      col2     3     2     3     4      2.0
C      col2     2     4     6     4      4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cond = ([df.columns.values[1:]] * df.shape[0]) == df.flag.values.reshape(-1,1)
df1 = df.set_index('flag', append=True)
df1.join(df1.where(cond).ffill(axis=1).col4.rename('res')).reset_index('flag')
```